Actualizar los datos de una ventana hijo a un treeview de la ventana padre
Estoy realizando una aplicación, tengo una ventana padre y una ventana hijo. Al abrir la ventana hijo(Paciente), guardo los datos solicitados en la base de datos(mongodb), hasta allí todo funciona bien, sin embargo, cuando cierro dicha ventana debería actualizar los datos de manera automática en la ventana padre, en el treeview, he realizado y leído muchos tutoriales y no logro, no sé que hago mal.
Tango la idea que debo hacer el llamado de la función mostrarDatos en el módulo crear_registro, lo llamo de esta manera: mostrarDatos(self.tree), y me envía el siguiente error: TypeError: nuevoPaciente() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
Necesito una mano amiga. Gracias
index.py
from manager import Manager

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = Manager()
        app.mainloop()

container.py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
import mostrar_paciente as mp
from paciente import Paciente
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Container(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, padre, controlador):
        super().__init__(padre)
        self.controlador = controlador
        self.pack()
        self.place(x=0, y=0, width=1360, height=700)
        self.config(bg="white")
        self.widgets()

    def show_frame(self, container):
        top_level = tk.Toplevel(self)
        frame = container(top_level)
        frame.config(bg="white")
        frame.pack(fill = "both", expand=True)
        top_level.geometry("1100x650+120+20")
        top_level.resizable(False,False)

    def paciente(self):
        self.show_frame(Paciente)
        
    

    def widgets(self):
        frame1 = tk.Frame(self, bg="white")
        frame1.pack()
        frame1.place(x=0, y=0, width=1360, height=700)

        btnCrearPaciente = Button(frame1, bg= "#009587", fg="white", text="Nuevo",font="sans 8 bold",  command=self.paciente)
        btnCrearPaciente.place(x=30, y=20, width=70, height=70)

        style = ttk.Style(frame1)
        style.theme_use('clam')

        style.configure('Treeview.Heading', background="#009587", foreground="white", font="sans 10 bold")

        treFrame = tk.Frame(frame1, bg=("#009587"))
        treFrame.place(x=330, y=120, width=1000, height= 500)

        scrol_y = ttk.Scrollbar(treFrame, orient= VERTICAL)
        scrol_y.pack(side= RIGHT, fill= Y)
        scrol_x = ttk.Scrollbar(treFrame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        scrol_x.pack(side= BOTTOM, fill= X)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(treFrame, columns=("Cédula", "Primer Apellido", "Segundo Apellido", "Nombres"), show="headings", 
                                height=10, yscrollcommand=scrol_y.set,xscrollcommand=scrol_x.set)

        scrol_y.config(command=self.tree.yview)
        scrol_x.config(command=self.tree.xview)
        
        self.tree.heading("#1", text="Cédula")
        self.tree.heading("#2", text="Primer Apellido")
        self.tree.heading("#3", text="Segundo Apellido")
        self.tree.heading("#4", text="Nombres")

        self.tree.column("Cédula", anchor="center")
        self.tree.column("Primer Apellido", anchor="center")
        self.tree.column("Segundo Apellido", anchor="center")
        self.tree.column("Nombres", anchor="center")

        self.tree.pack(expand= True, fill=BOTH)        
        mp.mostrarDatos(self.tree)     

manager.py
from tkinter import Tk, Frame
from container import Container

class Manager(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Software Odontológico")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.configure(bg="#0a89d4")
        self.geometry("1360x700+0+0")

        self.container = Frame(self, bg="#0a89d4")
        self.container.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.frames={
            Container: None
        }

        self.load_frame()
        self.show_frame(Container)
    
    def load_frame(self):
        for FrameClass in self.frames.keys():
            frame = FrameClass(self.container, self)
            self.frames[FrameClass] = frame
    
    def show_frame(self, frame_class):
        frame = self.frames[frame_class]
        frame.tkraise()
    
def main():
    app = Manager
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

database.py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from pymongo import MongoClient

@contextmanager
def get_paciente_collection():
    client = None
    try:
        client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
        base_datos = client["odontoBd"] #nombre base de datos
        collection = base_datos["paciente"] #Se crea la coleccion
        yield collection
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"Error de conexión a la base de datos prueba: {ex}")
    finally:
        if client is not None:
            client.close()

crear_registro.py
from database import get_paciente_collection

def nuevoPaciente(
        self,
        entry_cedula, 
        entry_primerApe, 
        entry_segundoApe        
        ):

    documents = {
        '_id': entry_cedula,
        'primerApe': entry_primerApe,
        'segundoApe': entry_segundoApe
        }
    with get_paciente_collection() as collection:
        collection.insert_one(documents)
mostrarDatos(self.tree)

mostrar_paciente.py
from database import get_paciente_collection

def mostrarDatos(tree):
    with get_paciente_collection() as collection:
        
            documents = tree.get_children()
            for document in documents:
                tree.delete(document)
            for document in collection.find():
                tree.insert('', 0, values=(document["_id"], document["primerApe"], document["segundoApe"]))

paciente
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
import crear_registro as cr

class Paciente(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):
        frame1 = tk.Frame(self, bg="#009587", highlightbackground="gray", highlightthickness=1)
        frame1.pack()
        frame1.place(x=0, y=0, width=1100, height=100)

        titulo = tk.Label(self, text="Pacientes", bg="#009587", font="sans 30 bold", anchor="center",fg="white")
        titulo.pack()
        titulo.place(x=5, y=0, width=1090, height=90)
        
        frame2 = tk.Frame(self, bg="white",highlightbackground="gray", highlightthickness=1)
        frame2.place(x=0, y= 100, width=1100, height=550)

        lblframe = LabelFrame(frame2, text= "Información del Paciente", bg="white", font="sans 12 bold",fg=("#009587"))
        lblframe.place(x=10, y=10, width=1060, height=80)

        label_num_historia = tk.Label(lblframe, text=("Historia N°"), fg=("#009587"), font="sans 11 bold")
        label_num_historia.place(x=10, y=10)
        self.num_historia = tk.StringVar()
        self.entryNumHistoria = ttk. Entry(lblframe, textvariable= self.num_historia, state= "readonly", font="sans 11 bold")
        self.entryNumHistoria.place(x=100, y=10, width=80)

        label_num_historia = tk.Label(lblframe, text=("Cédula N°"), fg=("#009587"), font="sans 11 bold")
        label_num_historia.place(x=200, y=10)
        self.entryCedula = ttk. Entry(lblframe,  font="sans 11")
        self.entryCedula.place(x=285, y=10)

        label_primerApe = tk.Label(lblframe, text=("Primer \nApellido"), fg=("#009587"), font="sans 11 bold")
        label_primerApe.place(x=470, y=0)
        self.entry_primerApe = ttk. Entry(lblframe, font="sans 11")
        self.entry_primerApe.place(x=560, y=10)

        label_segundoApe = tk.Label(lblframe, text=("Segundo \nApellido"), fg=("#009587"), font="sans 11 bold")
        label_segundoApe.place(x=770, y=0)
        self.entry_segundoApe = ttk. Entry(lblframe, font="sans 11")
        self.entry_segundoApe.place(x=860, y=10)

        lblframe1 = LabelFrame(frame2, text="Opciones",bg="white", font="sans 12 bold",fg=("#009587"))
        lblframe1.place(x=10, y=380, width=1060, height=100)

        boton_agregar = tk.Button(lblframe1, text="Agregar Paciente", bg= "#009587", fg="white", font="sans 14 bold",  
                                    command=lambda: cr.nuevoPaciente(
                                    self.entryCedula.get(),
                                    self.entry_primerApe.get(), 
                                    self.entry_segundoApe.get()))        
        boton_agregar.place(x=50, y=10, width=240, height=50)

        boton_buscar = tk.Button(lblframe1, text="Buscar Paciente", bg= "#009587", fg="white", font="sans 14 bold")
        boton_buscar.place(x=350, y=10, width=240, height=50)

        boton_nuevoP = tk.Button(lblframe1, text="Nuevo Paciente", bg= "#009587", fg="white", font="sans 14 bold")
        boton_nuevoP.place(x=650, y=10, width=240, height=50)


Buenas! Por lo que veo en el error, la función mostrarDatos requiere que le pases un argumento llamado self
Sin embargo, mostrarDatos tiene ningún parametro llamado así.
Se me ocurren dos razones por lo que esto suceda:

(1) la función que estás viendo en el editor es diferente a lo que python está ejecutando realmente.
Puede que, por ejemplo, los cambios hechos en el editor estén sin guardar.
Otra cosa que se puede hacer es ver en el traceback, que aparece arriba del mensaje de error, que "estaba sucediendo" antes del error.
(2) El código de la pregunta no se parece lo suficiente como para poder recrear el error. Para entender mejor este punto, por favor lee
ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable
